# ページ遷移するとログアウトになる

Tags: django

## 困っていること

アプリのセッションを保持してページ遷移を安定化させたい。

## 状況

掲示板アプリでログイン後に掲示板作成をしようとすると、ログアウト状態となり、掲示板作成ができない。
更新ボタンやその他ボタンを押すと、ログイン状態に戻り安定しない。

## 仮説

恐らくログインはできていて、セッションを保持できていないため、ページ遷移や更新ボタンを押すたびに未ログイン/ログイン済みを行ったり来たりしている？

## settings.py

```
(略)
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'accounts',
    'board',
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 3600
(略)
```